# Moving specific div tag from one container to another in the same page

Tags: jquery, onclick, tags, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I have new div tags being generated with a `onclick` event, and that works fine. I have created and appended a new button on each div tag in case a user wants to delete that div tag and that works fine. BUT I cannot figure out how to move a specific row with all its info and buttons from my `#first` container to my `#second` container

I've tried figuring it out with appendTo since the jQuery documentation mentions that we can also select an element on the page and insert it into another y utilizing `appendTo`.

```
  var itineraryInput = $("#search").val();

  var row="";
  row+="<div class='attraction'>";
  row+="<p>" + itineraryInput + "</p>";
  row+="<button class='newButton review'>Add to  leave a review</button>";
  row+="<button class='newButton something'>Do something</button>";
  row+="<button class='newButton deleteButton'>Remove itinerary</button>";
  row+="</div>";

  $("#first").prepend(row);
})

$(document).on("click", ".deleteButton", function() {
    $(this).closest(".attraction").remove();
});


//This is the part that is not working!!!!

$(document).on("click", "something", function() {
   $("div").appendTo("#second");
})
```

I need to see a row move from one container to the other on the same page.

Comment: In case anyone wants to assist:

https://jsfiddle.net/4phguwrL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first correct the code as `.something` instead of `something` for your click listener. Then, you can use the `closest()` to get the entire `div` and append using the `appendTo()`

```js
$("#search-submit").on("click", function() {

  var itineraryInput = $("#search").val();

  var row = "";
  row += "<div class='attraction'>";
  row += "<p>" + itineraryInput + "</p>";
  row += "<button class='newButton review'>Add to  leave a review</button>";
  row += "<button class='newButton something'>Do something</button>";
  row += "<button class='newButton deleteButton'>Remove itinerary</button>";
  row += "</div>";

  $("#first").prepend(row);
})

$(document).on("click", ".deleteButton", function() {
  $(this).closest(".attraction").remove();
});

$(document).on("click", ".something", function() {
  $(this).closest('.attraction').appendTo("#second");
})
```

```css
.newButton {
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 100%"></div>
<div class="row mb-2">
  <div class="col">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search for an attraction...">
    <button id="search-submit" class="btn btn-lg pull-right">Add To Your Itinerary!</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="trans_container">
  <div id="trans_first"></div>
  <div id="trans_second"></div>
</div>

<div class="acontainer">
  <div id="first"></div>
  <div id="second"></div>
  <div id="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that! Is there a way to remove the ```review``` and ```something``` buttons once moved to the second container?

Comment: you can use the `$('#second .attraction').last()` to get the last appended value, and the use the `find()` and `remove()` to find and remove the needed elements

Comment: this doesn't look right: ```$('#second .attraction').last().find(".review .something").remove(".review .something");``` haha

Comment: wrong mate, try this way please `$('#second .attraction').last().find(".review, .something").remove()`